# DotNetRDF sparql query to get subjects with a specific resource

Tags: c#, rdf, sparql, authorize.net-cim, dotnetrdf

I have a little problem with a Sparql query. I would like to get all subjects having the type "TopologicalNode", with a predicate called "BaseVoltage" and a specific resource (in this example, '#_2a9')

There is a sample of my .xml

```
<cim:TopologicalNode rdf:ID="_f4d">   
    <cim:IdentifiedObject.name>dj</cim:IdentifiedObject.name>
    <cim:TopologicalNode.BaseVoltage rdf:resource="#_2a9"/>
</cim:TopologicalNode>

<cim:TopologicalNode rdf:ID="_738">    
    <cim:IdentifiedObject.name>iT</cim:IdentifiedObject.name>
    <cim:TopologicalNode.BaseVoltage rdf:resource="#_a5c"/>   
</cim:TopologicalNode>

<cim:TopologicalNode>
    <cim:TopologicalNode rdf:ID="_2a2">
    <cim:IdentifiedObject.name>Hi</cim:IdentifiedObject.name>
    <cim:TopologicalNode.BaseVoltage rdf:resource="#_2a9"/>
    <cim:TopologicalNode.ConnectivityNodeContainer rdf:resource="#_d7a"/>
</cim:TopologicalNode>
```

My query doesn't work (Encountered a Token which terminates a Triple Pattern but there are too many Tokens to form a valid Triple Pattern)

```
"SELECT ?s  WHERE {?s rdf:type cim:TopologicalNode; cim:TopologicalNode.BaseVoltage ?o rdf:resource '#_2a9';}"
```

I also tried to put directly the full URI... Same error!

```
"SELECT ?s  WHERE {?s rdf:type cim:TopologicalNode; cim:TopologicalNode.BaseVoltage ?o rdf:resource <example.org/EQ#_2a9>;}"
```

What is my mistake ? It must be in the third block because I saw that this was working

```
"SELECT ?s  WHERE {?s rdf:type cim:TopologicalNode; cim:TopologicalNode.BaseVoltage ?o }"
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: I am confused by the number of quotation marks in your strings. Could you show just the SPARQL expressions as they are sent to the endpoint, without any host language quoting or escaping?

Comment: I'm sorry I edited my post. There is what query.CommandText contains :                      SELECT ?s  WHERE {?s rdf:type cim:TopologicalNode; cim:TopologicalNode.BaseVoltage ?o rdf:resource <http://example.org/EQ#_2a9>}

Comment: Providing the full error message (which likely contains a line and column number) plus the stack trace would be helpful.  Also what version of dotNetRDF is this?

Comment: RDF Version : 1.0.3.0, Runtime version : v4.0.30319 .The error is in the uri, at # character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is invalid SPARQL, if you include some white space you can easily see this:

```
SELECT ?s  
WHERE 
{
  ?s rdf:type cim:TopologicalNode ; 
     cim:TopologicalNode.BaseVoltage ?o rdf:resource '#_2a9' ;
}
```

After the `?o` you immediately state another predicate and object pair but fail to include any additional punctuation to separate the tokens and indicate a new triple pattern so the parser is quite right to give you this error.  Of course the error could be more helpful but that's a separate issue.

You can fix your query by inserting an additional semicolon character like so:

```
SELECT ?s  
WHERE 
{
  ?s rdf:type cim:TopologicalNode ; 
     cim:TopologicalNode.BaseVoltage ?o ;
     rdf:resource '#_2a9' ;
}
```

Btw you still won't actually get any results because `rdf:resource` is merely a serialisation detail of RDF/XML and will not show up in your data.  What you probably meant was simply to use the URI in place of `?o` like so:

```
SELECT ?s  
WHERE 
{
  ?s rdf:type cim:TopologicalNode ; 
     cim:TopologicalNode.BaseVoltage <http://example.org#_2a9> ;
}
```

Of course you may still need to tweak this slightly to use the correct URI here but this should point you in the right direction

Comment: I think I managed to resolve it, I let you know in few minutes. Thank you @RobV !